# Jquery CSS height Toggle

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, conditional-statements

I am using this code to show/hide a div, by changing its height:

```
$("#about").click(function(){
    if ($('#descrition').css('height') === '280px') {
        $("#description").css("height","0px");
    } else {
        $("#description").css("height","280px");
    }  
});
```

It works to expand the div, but doesn't when I click again to hide it. Any ideas?

PS: the change in height is important, as I use css transitions to animate the div, so display  changes aren't an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will both fix your problem and speed up the code, removing the repeated jQuery parses...

```
$("#about").click(function() {
    var $description = $("#description");
    if ($description.height() === 280) {
        $description.height(0);
    } else {
        $description.height(280);
    }
});
```

As pointed out by putvande, there was a typo whilst trying to get the height.  The above also stores the jQuery object as a local variable, rather than parsing the DOM repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have a typo.

In your first line you check `('#descrition').css('height')` instead of `('#description').css('height')`.

But you could also use:

```
$('#description').height();
```

But that gives a value without the 'px'.

Comment: You get my +1, but I've added a little more below.